# Is scientific racism a pseudoscience?

Tags: biology, race

In Wikipedia, in the [list of pseudoscientific topics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_topics_characterized_as_pseudoscience#Racial_theories) included the following "pseudosciences": Scientific racism, Aryanism and Melanin theory.

While it is quite evident that Aryanism and Melanin theory can be easily classified as pseudoscience, Scientific racism is defined as follows:

> claim that scientific evidence shows the inferiority or superiority of
>   certain races, or alternatively the claim of "classifying" individuals
>   of different phenotypes into discrete races or ethnicities

Since this claim is described as pseudoscientific, I wonder whether it was ever proven that

- people of different phenotypes cannot be classifyed into different races

When I was studying in the school in the 1990s we were taught that there are three main races: Europeoid, Mongoloid and Negroid, we were taught that people Europeoid race have more body hair, Negroid race has darker skin, big lips and curled hair and people of Mongoloid race have epicantus. We of course were told that not all people represent pure features characteristic for these races due to mixing. Was this view refuted since then?

- there is no scientific evidence indicating superiority or inferiority of people of different racial/ethnic origin in different fields

I remember I read a study indicating unequal distribution of IQ index over races, ethnicities and countries. Is composing such statistics also now considered pseudoscience?

Comment: [IQ and the wealth of nations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IQ_and_the_Wealth_of_Nations) has been described variously as pseudoscience or bad science, is at the very least highly controversial.

Answer (score 1):

I don't if that could be classified as superiority of inferiority, since I'd say that is just some characteristic: there are some research about drugs that could benefit more one race than another (if you also accept that there are some difference races among humans)

- [BiDil: indications and dosage](http://www.rxlist.com/bidil-drug/indications-dosage.htm) is an approved drugs for heart conditions, and it's indicated to `self-identified black patients`.

There are some opinions that we couldn't define human races (like [this](http://www.councilforresponsiblegenetics.org/ViewPage.aspx?pageId=79)), and so perhaps even racial drugs are a misleading theme.